# Get all contacts from Google Contacts API version 3.0

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to retrieve all the contacts from my Gmail account.  At the moment it only seems to randomly get about 25 (I have about 200 contacts in the My Contacts group).  What I have noticed is that these contacts that are retrieved are all old contacts that I made a long time ago.  The newer contacts don't seem to show.

**OAuth2Token**

> ```
> token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scope=SCOPE, user_agent=USER_AGENT)
> redirect_url = token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
> ```

**Redirect for Auth**

> ```
> self.redirect(redirect_url)
> ```

**Auth, Get Contacts and Display**

> ```
> url = atom.http_core.Uri.parse_uri(self.request.uri)
> if 'error' in url.query:
>   pass
> else:
>   token.get_access_token(url.query)
>
>   gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient()
>   token.authorize(gd_client)
>   feed = gd_client.GetContacts()
>
> for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
>   self.response.write(entry.name.full_name)
> ```

In the [Developer Contacts Page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index#getting_started) the 'Running the sample code' says to use:

> gd_client =
>   gdata.contacts.data.ContactsClient(source='YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME')

But it keeps kicking out an error that the ContactsClient was not found.  I eventually found it in `gdata.contacts.client`.

---

Additional question - I have assigned `USER_AGENT` with '', what am I supposed to put there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contacts feed returns the first 25 contacts when no query parameters are provided. Add the start-index and max-results parameters to adjust this.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters

There should also be page info returned in the result indicating how many contacts are on the page, which page it is, and how many more pages there are.

Comment: Additional question - I have assigned USER_AGENT with '', what am I supposed to put there?

Comment: User-agents are arbitrary strings that are sent in the HTTP header to help the server identify which program is sending the request. While an empty string is technically valid, you probably want to set this to your application name along with your version num e.g. "MyApp/1.0"

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

Click on the Python tab to see how to add query parameters. The list of all parameters are listed below.